# CIL - What is the difference between ldc.i4 33 and ldc.i4.33?

Tags: .net, cil, opcode

I'm trying to figure out some CIL code. But it seems these two statements do the same thing (according to everything I have read).

`ldc.i4 33`

and

`ldc.i4.33`

Both supposedly "load an int32 onto the stack of value 33".

Is this correct? Why? I would have thought that `ldc.i4.33` would be "load an integer from local variable index 33 onto the stack".

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: ldc.i4.33 does not exist. May I ask, where did you get it from? You can find the list of valid opcodes in ECMA-335, partition III, section 1.2.1

Comment: Well I saw ldc.i4.1 and I saw ldc.i4 33 and I didn't know there were "macro opcodes" so I assumed ldc.i4.33 was the same, but I was confused about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The opcode `ldc.i4.33` doesn't exist.

There's a few special (called macro) opcodes, from:

```
ldc.i4.m1  // has the same effect as: ldc.i4 -1
```

to

```
ldc.i4.8   // has the same effect as: ldc.i4  8
```

But they are just a short form of the `ldc.i4` opcode, for common cases, to optimize the CIL size.

Similarly, `ldloc.0` is a short form (i.e. has a more compact CIL encoding, but is doing exactly the same as) `ldloc 0`, etc.

Comment: Oh. No wonder I was confused. So this is also a valid opcode I take it (which is what stemmed my confusion): _ldc.i4.0_? And I think ldloc is the opcode for storing the value of a local variable on the stack, for instance ldloc.2 stores the value of local variable index 2 on the stack. Is this all correct?

Comment: No, ld is the prefix for load. So `ldloc.2` loads the variable at index 2 on the stack. st is the prefix for store, so `stloc.2` stores the value on the stack in the variable at index 2. And yes, `ldc.i4.0` is a valid opcode, and is a short form of `ldc.i4 0`

Comment: JB: That's what I meant, I just used the word "store" as a synonym for "load", which is wrong (**slaps wrist**). Thanks for the clarifying answers!